# Does bootstrap have a chart component with time frame option?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

[This image comes from the web result from google when searching for the rate of anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtjJo.png)

I want to make this kind of chart but apparently, I don't know what it's called so I cannot search for this kind of component. Is it possible to create it using bootstrap line chart?

Answer (score 0):

I guess Bootstrap doesn't have this type charts but you can check this out this web site.

https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/index.html